# why deleting a node in XML file doesn't update the XML structure?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

hello I have been studying XML all day on w3school website and I reached to removing nodes chapter but when I remove a node the XML file structure does not change I mean the node is still there why?

here is the example

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
<book>
    <title>Animals</title>
    <price>50</price>
    <color>red</color>
</book> 
<book>
    <title>Humans</title>
    <price>50</price>
    <color>blue</color>
</book>
 </books>
```

here is html and javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
        Project Name
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="connect()">Click</button>
    <p id="demo">Mohammad</p>


   <script>
        function connect(){
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
              if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status==200)
                  {
                      myfunction(xhttp);
                  }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET","test.xml",true);
            xhttp.send();
        }

       function myfunction(xml){
           xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
           var root = xmlDoc.documentElement;
           var currNode = root.childNodes[1];
           removedNode = currNode.removeChild(currNode.childNodes[3]);
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
           "Removed node: " + removedNode.nodeName;
       }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you check whether the XML has been updated? Assuming you opened the original XML file to check: the codes modified XML object in memory, but didn't write it back to the file/disk afterwards..

Comment: yeah this is what I did I opened the original file to check but the problem is when I tried to access a text node inside element node which I have already delete it then its still shown like nothing happened isn't there a way to update the file ?

Comment: Interesting. You tag XSLT but don't use it. And removing nodes in XSLT is effortless!

Comment: yeah I tagged it so more people can see my question but can't you answer my question?